# Can gradient descent optimize subtraction of two objective functions (minimize one and maximize the other)?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, neural-networks

If the problem in a neural network is to optimize on one set of parameters and the loss function is:

$$E(\theta) = loss1(a, b) - loss2(b)$$

can gradient descent minimize $E(\theta)$ in this problem, which means minimize $loss1$ and maximize $loss2$. In another words, can we find such $\theta$?

Comment: yes, put an absolute value or square around it, then it will be non negative, and minimising $E(\theta)$ will maximise loss2 and minimise loss 1.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst do you mean $E(\theta) = |loss1(a, b) - loss2(b)|$?

Comment: yeah, or $E(\theta) = (loss1(a,b)-loss2(b))^2$ as it is differentiable.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot simultaneously solve two different objectives by minimizing one, in the general case. You can obtain a solution which tries to find a compromise of the objectives, but that's another thing.

Trivial counterexample n your case is $l_1(a,b) = a^2+b^2$ and $l_2 = b^2$. The cost  $l_1(a,b)$ is minimized by $a=b=0$ while $l_2$ is maximized by $b=\pm \infty$ while the cost $l_1(a,b)-l_2(b)$ is minimized by $a=0$ and $b$ arbitrary.